# Flutter & AlertDialog : How to stretch a container so that it has the same width with the AlertDialog box?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-alertdialog

I have been trying to make a button in `AlertDialog` box in Flutter. But I cannot find a way to stretch the button container. Please check my code and see the example picture below.

```
AlertDialog(
                    title: Center(child: Text("Picture")),
                    content: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          width: width,
                          //height: height,
                          child: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
                            placeholder: kTransparentImage,
                            image: image.url,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            height: 50,
                            width: width,
                            color: primaryColor,
                            child: Text(
                              'Okay',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
```

[image]

Please help me in this. I am looking forward to hearing your opinion. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AlertDialog` has a `default content padding` of `24` logical pixels to the right, left and bottom of the `AlertDialog` to separate the content from the other edges of the dialog..

To Make the `Button` fit the `AlertDialog` width, you will need to give the `AlertDialog` a `padding` of `zero` and apply `paddings` to others widgets except the `Button`.

I added an example using your code:

---

```dart
     AlertDialog(
                    // change the default padding to zero
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    title: Center(child: Text("Picture")),
                    content: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: <Widget>[
                         // wrap your container with a padding widget
                         Padding(
                         padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0), // give a preferred padding
                         child: Container(
                         width: width,
                         //height: height,
                         placeholder: kTransparentImage,
                         image: image.url,
                            ),
                           ),
                          ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            height: 50,
                            width: width,
                            color: primaryColor,
                            child: Text(
                              'Okay',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
```